# wcf self hosting jquery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I'm trying to call an wcf self hosted method from jquery but, i'm aways getting the message: "method not allowed". I found some answers to this issue on this forum but nothing worked to me....
ps. It works fine when I add the reference on a console app and consume it.

it's an windows forms self-hosted app

form load:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServices), new Uri[] { });
host.Open();
```

App.Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig" name="MyServices">
                <endpoint address="srv" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Operations" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceConfig">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Operation Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Test();
```

Service:

```
public string Test()
{
return "Good!";
}
```

JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8766/Test",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    //data: '{}', // tried passing data
    type: "GET", // tried POST and pass nothing(deleting this param), but nothing...
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your current problem is caused by the fact that `WebInvoke`, when you don't specify the `Method` parameter, will default to "POST".  Your jQuery code is issuing a "GET" request, so the "method not allowed" error would be expected.

However, your comment about trying GET initially and getting nothing in return makes me lean towards your problem being a violation of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) with your browser.  Since you're hosting the service in a Windows Form with the address of `http://localhost:8766`, I'm assuming your web site is not located at `http://localhost:8766'.  Per the same origin policy:

> The term "origin" is defined using the
>   domain name, application layer
>   protocol, and (in most browsers) TCP
>   port of the HTML document running the
>   script. Two resources are considered
>   to be of the same origin if and only
>   if all these values are exactly the
>   same.

If you're returning data from your service in JSON format, you may want to consider using a GET request that returns JSONP.  This type of request does not violate the same origin policy as requesting remote scripts are allowed.  Your jQuery call would then look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8766/Test",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    processData: false,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Since you're using `WebInvoke`, you may also want to use the `WebHttpBinding` binding instead of `BasicHttpBinding`.  `WebInvoke` doesn't work unless it's used with `WebHttpBinding`.  And when you use `WebHttpBinding`, you can customize it so that it responds to JSONP requests.  So your config would look like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfig" name="MyServices">
            <endpoint address="srv" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Operations" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8766" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceConfig">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here's a very good blog [post](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/) that steps you through this.

Hopefully this helps!